# How to run commands with back slash?

Tags: docker, command-line, cmd, strapi

I'm using windows and I want to run docker with [strapi image](https://github.com/strapi/strapi-docker).

I did this command: `docker pull strapi/strapi`

Then I want to do this command (in cmd):

```
docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app \
           -e DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo \
           -e DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo \
           -e DATABASE_PORT=27017 \
           -e DATABASE_NAME=strapi \
           -v `pwd`/strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app \
           --link strapi-mongo:mongo \
           -p 1337:1337 \
           --name strapi -d strapi/strapi
```

but how should I execute this? I got this error from the cmd:

```
docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app \                                                
docker: invalid reference format.                                                  
See 'docker run --help'.                                                           

-e DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo \                                                         
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

-e DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo \                                                    
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

-e DATABASE_PORT=27017 \                                                           
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

-e DATABASE_NAME=strapi \                                                          
'-e' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

-v `pwd`/strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app \                                      
'-v' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

--link strapi-mongo:mongo \                                                        
'--link' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                     
operable program or batch file.                                                    

-p 1337:1337 \                                                                     
'-p' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                         
operable program or batch file.                                                    

--name strapi -d strapi/strapi                                                     
'--name' is not recognized as an internal or external command,                     
operable program or batch file.
```

If I run it as one line:

```
docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo DATABASE_PORT=27017 DATABASE_NAME=strapi -v `pwd`/strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app --link strapi-mongo:mongo -p 1337:1337 --name strapi -d strapi/strapi
```

I got error:

```
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Comment: Put it on one line.

Comment: I got error message:`docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with CMD. Windows is case insensitive.

Comment: `-v \`pwd\`` makes no sense. cmd doesn't understand backticks.

Comment: When you put it on one line, you must still repeat the `-e` option. (The backslash in Linux is only used to mask the following newline. All the rest must be present).

Answer (score 2):

On windows, instead of using backslash (), you have to use backtick (`)

```
docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app `
           -e DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo `
           -e DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo `
           -e DATABASE_PORT=27017 `
           -e DATABASE_NAME=strapi `
           -v `pwd`/strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app `
           --link strapi-mongo:mongo `
           -p 1337:1337 `
           --name strapi -d strapi/strapi
```

Comment: I'm using CMD (not PowerShell) and it doesn't work using backtick. What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the command in below mentioned format :

```
docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app -e DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo -e DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo -e DATABASE_PORT=27017 -e DATABASE_NAME=strapi -v `pwd`/strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app --link strapi-mongo:mongo -p 1337:1337 --name strapi -d strapi/strapi
```

Comment: got error: `docker: Error response from daemon: create `pwd`/strapi-app: "`pwd`/strapi-app" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path. See 'docker run --help'.`

Comment: docker run -e APP_NAME=strapi-app -e DATABASE_CLIENT=mongo -e DATABASE_HOST=strapi-mongo -e DATABASE_PORT=27017 -e DATABASE_NAME=strapi -v /strapi-app:/usr/src/api/strapi-app --link strapi-mongo:mongo -p 1337:1337 --name strapi -d strapi/strapi

Comment: Probably you have to update server.json config file